# Is there a way to use a switch a constants file based on configuration in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a constant file in Vue that I want to switch based on a specific brand. I know that you can use  a config file based on environment like dev & prod. But haven't really found any information if it's possible to do this based on a specific setting (brand). I'm using the same components just slightly different paths where it needs it information from, currently this is hardcoded to 1 path.

Comment: what kind of file do you need to "swtich"? do you mean you need to change the `import` statement depending on the brand?

Comment: yeah something like that indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the environement variables by using `process.env.brand`, so if you want to change the `import` statement based on the value of the brand you should first change the `import` statement to use `require(...)` instead and then do something like the following:

```js
if (process.env.brand === 'Some Brand') {
  var path = '/path/to/file'
} else {
  var path = '/another/path/to/file'
}

const Component = require(path)
```

Have in mind that the `import` statement can't be used in this case because it only accepts string literals as the module path.

Comment: `path` would be out of scope

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Edited.